# Getter Setter method being called at wrong order

Tags: java, android, methods, static, getter-setter

i need some help. Im making this app which parses the bible and displays it in a webView.
I implemented a back next/passage feature into the app. its calling the correct json address but iv´e got some issues with the order in which the getters and setters are being called.

This is the code block which calls the static method in order to get a string as a response:

```
 String previousPassage = BackNextGo.getPassage
                    (currentChapter, chapterSelected);       
 L.m("previousPassage");
```

And this are the methods it calls:

```
public class BackNextGo {

    private BackNextGo() {
    }

    private static String requestUrl;
    private static RequestQueue queue;

    private static String s;

    public static String getPassage(String data, int chapterSelected) {
        setRequestUrl(data, chapterSelected);
        queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
        sendJsonRequest();
        return getData();
    }

    private static void setRequestUrl(String s, int chapterSelected) {
        requestUrl = Constants.DISPLAY_DATA_URL_PART_1
                + s.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)",
                        String.valueOf(chapterSelected))
                        + Constants.DISPLAY_DATA_URL_PART_2 + Constants.BIBLE_API_KEY;
    }

    private static String getRequestUrl() {
        return requestUrl;
    }

    private static void sendJsonRequest() {
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                getRequestUrl(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                if (response == null || response.length() == 0) {

                } else {

                    try {
                        setData(response
                                .getString(Constants.Keys.Books.KEY_SELECTED_CHAPTER));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
    }

    public static String getData() {
        counter++;
        L.m("getter method");
        return s;
    }

    private static void setData(String data) {
        s = data;
        L.m("setter method");
    }
}
```

I have placed toasts on the getter and setter method as well as on the method calling the BackNextPassage static class.

and the order is:

1) getter method

2) calling code block (String)

3) setter method

To my understanding, the order should be: first the setter method. becouse it is called from within the "sendJsonRequest" method and then the getData or getter method, and finally the calling method.

This sucks becouse everytime i call the BackNextPassage class im getting the data set by the last call. Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

ps:

L("some random text"); these are normal toasts like: Toast.makeText(context, "........show();

UPDATE!:

So i tried synchronizing the methods but it just hangs until the app crashes...
Heres my code: (maybe someone can point out my mistake? =) )

```
public class BackNextGo {

private static BackNextGo instance = null;
private String requestUrl;
private RequestQueue queue;
private String s;

private BackNextGo() {
}

public static BackNextGo getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new BackNextGo();
    }
    return instance;
}

public String getPassage(String data, int chapterSelected) {
    setRequestUrl(data, chapterSelected);
    queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    synchronized (this) {
        sendJsonRequest();

        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return getData();
}

private void setRequestUrl(String s, int chapterSelected) {
    requestUrl = Constants.DISPLAY_DATA_URL_PART_1 + s.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)", String.valueOf(chapterSelected)) + Constants.DISPLAY_DATA_URL_PART_2 + Constants.BIBLE_API_KEY;
    System.out.println(requestUrl);
}

private String getRequestUrl() {
    return requestUrl;
}

private void sendJsonRequest() {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getRequestUrl()
            , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            if (response == null || response.length() == 0) {

            } else {

                try {
                    setData(response.getString(Constants.Keys.Books.KEY_SELECTED_CHAPTER));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}

private void setData(String data) {
    synchronized (this) {
        s = data;
        notify();
    }
}

public String getData() {
    return s;
}
}
```

and again... heres the code calling the class:

```
String previousPassage = BackNextGo.getInstance().getPassage(currentChapter, chapterSelected);
```

Comment: Don't make everything `static`!

Comment: To clarify the comment above, when all your methods are static it's usually a sign that you are not using object oriented principles properly.

Comment: From what I understand about your problem, you should be setting proviousPassage after the request is made. You can do this with an interface that is passed into the getPassage method from the calling class. Essentially it is a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So create your interface in BackNextGo

```
public class BackNextGo {

public interface OnData {
    public void updateData(String data);
}

private BackNextGo() {
}

private static String requestUrl;
private static RequestQueue queue;

private static String s;
private OnData sOnData = null;

public static String getPassage(String data, int chapterSelected, OnData onDataCallback) {
    sOnData = onDataCallback;
    setRequestUrl(data, chapterSelected);
    queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    sendJsonRequest();
    return getData();
}

private static void setRequestUrl(String s, int chapterSelected) {
    requestUrl = Constants.DISPLAY_DATA_URL_PART_1
            + s.replaceAll("\\s+", "").replaceAll("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)",
                    String.valueOf(chapterSelected))
                    + Constants.DISPLAY_DATA_URL_PART_2 + Constants.BIBLE_API_KEY;
}

private static String getRequestUrl() {
    return requestUrl;
}

private static void sendJsonRequest() {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            getRequestUrl(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            if (response == null || response.length() == 0) {

            } else {

                try {
                    setData(response
                            .getString(Constants.Keys.Books.KEY_SELECTED_CHAPTER));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}

public static String getData() {
    counter++;
    L.m("getter method");
    return s;
}

private static void setData(String data) {
    s = data;
    if(sOnData != null) {
        sOnData.updateData(data);
    }
    L.m("setter method");
}
}
```

Then in your calling class do something like...

```
String previousPassage;
OnData onDataCallback = new OnData {
    public void updateData(String data) {
        previousPassage = data;
    }
};
BackNextGo.getInstance().getPassage(currentChapter, chapterSelected, onDataCallback);
```

Comment: Would it be OK to make an activity and call startActivityForResult? That way I'm 100% sure the data will be set by the time it reaches the calling code. The activity wouldn't have a view obviously (I'd just specify that in the Android manifest). What I'm asking is would it be efficient/ OK to do?

Comment: No that is not efficient. It will not solve anything. The code you would put into the activity still has the asynchronous call. You would still need an interface in your calling activity to get a callback. You could get into [ReactiveX Android](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) But you might as well use the interface.

Comment: OK thanks man. I was just wondering cause I tried it out and it worked :/. But if it ain't efficient I guess I won't be doing it anymore thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

The order:

> 1) getter method
>
> 2) calling code block (String)
>
> 3) setter method

is not wrong! It is expected.. Let me elaborate on that..

You are assuming otherwise, mainly because of the order

```
sendJsonRequest(); // 'setter' method in here
return getData();  // 'getter' method here
```

is being called.

However, `sendJsonRequest()` takes time! The 'setter' method is only called within `onResponse(JSONObject response)`, that is, when the JSONRequest has been completed.

Therefore, once the `sendJsonRequest()` has been initiated, the next line `return getData()` is invoked immediately! This is why the 'getter' comes before the 'setter', unless the JSONRequest gets completed even faster than that (which is highly unlikely).

**Basically**, don't try to get the data immediately after you send out the JSON request. You should wait for the request to be completed, and issue some kind of callback to notify the requester that the data is ready, and the requester can get the data using `getData()`.

Comment: So what should i try? I already tried putting the sendJsonRequest(); in a thread and calling thread.join(); but i get the same result. What do you recomend i do?

Comment: @JoseMariaLanda Hi, I am not entirely familiar with these things.. Maybe you can google 'Asynchronous tasks', since the JSONObjectRequest is basically an asynchronous request that runs in the background without affecting your main thread. You will need some way to notify the caller that the data is ready, and the caller should only try to get the data upon notification.

Comment: Ill try that and post my results. Thanks

Comment: @JoseMariaLanda Really sorry for not being able to provide a better suggestion! Hope you are able to fix your issue soon :)